# How do I turn on logging in the Firebase Javascript client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm connecting to firebase from a Node.js module. My Javascript code is supposed to be writing data to my firebase, but it isn't. I'm also not seeing any errors, warnings, etc. logged to the console. So how do I crank up logging for the firebase JS client to see what's actually going on? Does such a thing exist? I tried searching the firebase API docs, but couldn't find anything.

I'm running my Node module with `node myModule.js` from the terminal in Mac OS X 10.9, in case it matters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To turn on logging, you can call:

```
Firebase.enableLogging(true);
```

And it'll log to the console. This logging is mostly meant for internal debugging purposes though; it's not super user-friendly.  But hopefully it'll help.

If you want to capture the messages programmatically instead of send them directly to the console, you can alternatively pass a function to enableLogging:

```
Firebase.enableLogging(function(logMessage) {
  // Add a timestamp to the messages.
  console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': ' + logMessage);
});
```

Comment: No. We don't currently document the log format or the fact that it exists. It's mostly used internally (by our support team, etc.).

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer Might I ask how to do it in swift?

Comment: @AlexBartiş I believe it's Firebase.setLoggingEnabled(true) if I recall.  Else, try contacting support@firebase.com They should be able to answer.

Comment: Yep, found it then! Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

In the 3.0.0 version of Firebase, this has been changed to:

```
firebase.database.enableLogging(true);
```

See [enableLoggging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.enableLogging).

Comment: + you can still use it programatically (even tho its not stated in their documentation), like in the previous example: firebase.database.enableLogging(function(logMessage) {
  // Add a timestamp to the messages.
  console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ': ' + logMessage);
});